# Reduced absorption coefficient question

Tags: optics, radiation, scattering, absorption, optical-lattices

I came across a paper that reads

> It is noteworthy that for a sample without lateral light propagation in the material, i.e. [reduced scattering] $\mu_s' = \infty$ and [absorption] $\mu_a=0$, ...

If there is no lateral light propagation from a collimated beam irradiating the surface of a turbid media, then this will mean that there is no scattering. Therefore, is the statement incorrect or what is the author indicating?

Reference:

- Determination of tissue optical properties by steady-state spatial frequency-domain reflectometry. N. Dögnitz & G. Wagnières. [*Laser Med. Sci.* **13**, 55 (1998)](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00592960); [réro eprint](http://doc.rero.ch/record/315452),  page 57

Comment: Maybe this is about the non-collimated case? Like sunlight in snow? Then there is no lateral transport of energy.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The statement is correct. Under an infinite  scattering coefficient  means wave will travel an infinite distance before it experiences a scattering. In other words, photons will not deviate to any lateral angle.